# Unity3D: как сделать коллекцию с подписанными полями, настраиваемую в инспекторе

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d, словари, коллекции

Использую ScriptableObject для хранения базовых статов типов существ в зависимости от их уровня (прогрессия не линейная)
Проблемы начались, когда я начал записывать коэффициент резиста к типам урона: если ужать все 8 "стихий" до одного массива, то получается что-то вот такое:

[image: Пример из инспектора]

[image: Пример из редактора]

Входящий урон умножается на значение элемента. 0 - полный игнор, 2 - 200% и т.д.

Но это же вот вообще ни разу не удобно! Что за "Элемент 0"? или "элемент 5"? Можно, конечно, условиться, что 0 - это рубящий, а 7 - огонь, но такое очень просто забыть и напортачить. Поэтому вместо этих вот "Элементов" хотелось бы конкретные подписи: Fire - 1.5, Cold - 0.1

Использовать восемь отдельный полей очень не хочется.

Пытался использовать вместо массива словарь с ключами из enum'a:

```
enum elem {fire, cold}
Dictionary<elem, float> res = new Dictionary<elem, float>();
```

Но эта сволочь не сериализуется и чтобы редактировать dict из инспектора надо навешивать кастомный обвес. А я слишком неумный для этого.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой тип данных тут использовать для доступной наглядности.

Answer (score 0):

Если массив состоит из структур или классов с `string` полем под именем `name` или `id`, то оно будет использоваться инспектором на именования элементов.

Но вообще что-бы код не был хлипким г на соплях. `Resistance` должен быть не массивом, а объектом, где нет возможности указать сколько там элементов, 8 или 7, а столько сколько есть видов. И запрос должен быть конечно не по абстрактному индексу, а `enum` типу. Можно написать кастумный инспектор, через `Editor` или `PropertyDrawer` для типа `Resistance`.